# Building RegEx Regular Expression

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I'm new to regular expressions and struggling to get my head around them!

What I'm trying to do is strip the EASW_ID value from the following text which gets treated as a string.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:widget="http://www.netvibes.com/ns/" xmlns:wpp="http://www.easportsworld.com/wpp/1.0">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Fifa Ultimate Team</title> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
     var HOST_DOMAIN = 'http://www.easports.com/';
     var EASW_ID = '123456789';
     var BUILD_CL = '123456';
     var BASE_FUT_URL = 'https://utas.fut.ea.com';
     var STATIC_ASSET_URL = '//www.easports.com/iframe/fut16';
     var CONTENT_URL = 'https://fifa15.content.easports.com';
```

The Id will be between 10-13 digits and the position that it is returned in the string can also change.

Am I correct in thinking that using a regular expression is the correct way to achieve this in ColdFusion? And, if so, how do I go about building a regular expression that'll meet my requirements?

Thanks

Comment: What engine are you using?

Comment: Doh! ColdFusion, will edit OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to delete this value from string? Then you can use:

```
REReplace("YourString","var EASW_ID = '[\d]*'; *","","ALL")
```

Result string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:widget="http://www.netvibes.com/ns/" xmlns:wpp="http://www.easportsworld.com/wpp/1.0"> <head> <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> <title>Fifa Ultimate Team</title> <script type="text/javascript"> var HOST_DOMAIN = 'http://www.easports.com/'; var BUILD_CL = '123456'; var BASE_FUT_URL = 'https://utas.fut.ea.com'; var STATIC_ASSET_URL = '//www.easports.com/iframe/fut16'; var CONTENT_URL = 'https://fifa15.content.easports.com';
```

if you want to grab digits:

```
REMatch("var EASW_ID = '([\d]*)", "YourString")
```

or

```
REMatch("var EASW_ID = '([\d]{9,13})", "YourString")
```

to specify number of digits. Parentheses - to specify captured text. `\d` means any digit. And * means that char can occur from 0 to any times. {9,13} Means from 9 to 13 times. Other characters treated as is.

Comment: I want to grab the digits between the apostrophe's, after the var EASW_ID =

Comment: Works a treat! Accepted answer. Thanks